# Removing Ubuntu 18.04 in Windows 10 WSL

Tags: 18.04, windows, uninstall, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have removed Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10 WSL but I am not sure if all the files have been deleted or not. How to be sure that all files are deleted?

Comment: Better to asked at: https://superuser.com

Comment: Why does it matter?  Do you actually worry about this if you uninstall any other package or feature on Windows?

Comment: Hi, I need to be sure to get get more space if all the files are properly removed.